# bootstrap carousel not working with multiple slides involve

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

hi guys I have this bootstrap carousel where I block different sliders according to the input checked, and it's working with changing the sliders, but when I go in the second or third slider the carousel stops moving.
code:
css:

```
 #f1 {
            display: block;
        }

        #f2 {
            display: none;
        }

        #f3 {
            display: none;
        }
```

html:

```
<input type="radio" id="a" name="e" value="a" checked>
    <input type="radio" id="b" name="e" value="b">
    <input type="radio" id="c" name="e" value="c">
    <label for="a">a</label>
    <label for="b">b</label>
    <label for="c">c</label>

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
                aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner c" id="f1">
            <div class="carousel-item active">

                a
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">

                b
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="carousel-inner d" id="f2">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                b
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">

                c
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner d" id="f3">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                c
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                d
            </div>

        </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $('input[type=radio][name=e]').change(function () {

            if (this.value == 'a') {
                $("#f2").css("display", "none");
                $("#f3").css("display", "none");
                $("#f1").css("display", "block");
            }
            else if (this.value == 'b') {
                $("#f1").css("display", "none");
                $("#f3").css("display", "none");
                $("#f2").css("display", "block");
                // alert("Transfer Thai Gayo");
            }
            else if (this.value == 'c') {
                $("#f1").css("display", "none");
                $("#f3").css("display", "block");
                $("#f2").css("display", "none");
                // alert("Transfer Thai Gayo");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I'm first doing taking a carousel from BOOTSTRAP, than I'm creating another inner carousel, than I'm creating to checkboxes that have different id but same name. for don't have both checked at the same time I'm using the class in the bottom in JQUERY and checking that they are not checked at the same time. Finally with CSS I'm displaying each inner carousel according to the checkbox checked, but somehow it's not working
how can I solve?

thanks.

Comment: What problem you are facing? does all three works? or nothing works? any error messages?

Comment: when I click the radio with id b, on the screen appears the second inner carousel and the letter b(the normal way it should be) at this point it's all ok but the problem is that the slider stops sliding it remains on the b, it should go to the second carousel it item that is c but it doesn't. the slider somehow continue moving, infact the INDICATORS move forward. this happens also with the third input but not with the first where all go smoothly